# how to add var object use event oninput?

Tags: javascript, object

I hope all of you always get good health body.
I have a script code as below:

```
<input id="range" type="range">
<p id="content"></p>

<script>

var range = document.getElementById('range');

var content = document.getElementById('content');
var object = {a: "1", b: "2", c:"3"};

range.oninput = function(){

content.innerHTML = range.value;

object.c = range.value;

}

</script>
```

but, there is no result on c object value.
Is there solution to add/custom object in var use javascript event?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You have a typo in objet.c = must be object.c =

Comment: Also, you're missing closing `"` after `type="range>` on your input

Comment: thanks @AdityaParab for your correction

Answer (score -1):

You had 2 typos in your original question (as described in the comments). These have now be edited.

Working snippet below:

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range');
var content = document.getElementById('content');

var object = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: "3"
};

range.oninput = function() {
  content.innerHTML = range.value;
  object.c = range.value;
  console.log(object);
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range">
<p id="content"></p>
```

Comment: thanks @Dan, I've done this script but I want to change the value of object {c} too, so {c} value is following to range value?

Comment: @4disk This line "object.c = range.value;" does exactly this. It assigns range.value to "c". You can use console.log(object) to check this.